# Propel ORM: originating save() re-triggered in cascaded save

Tags: php, propel

I have two Propel-based (Propel 1.6) model classes, FileUpload and Image:

```
<table name="file_upload">
  <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
  <column name="name" type="varchar" size="500" required="false" />
  <column name="mime_type" type="varchar" size="100" required="true" />
  <column name="data" type="blob" required="false" lazyLoad="true" />
</table>

<table name="image">
  <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
  <column name="file_upload_id" type="integer" required="true" />
  <foreign-key foreignTable="file_upload" onDelete="restrict">
    <reference local="file_upload_id" foreign="id" />   
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

When I instantiate a new Image $image, new FileUpload $upload, register $upload under $image and then try saving $image hoping for a cascaded save of both $image (second) and $upload (first) ...

```
$image = new Image();
$upload = new FileUpload();
// [set required properties in both models]
$image->setFileUpload( $image );
$image->save();
```

I get a foreign key violation error:

> Unable to execute UPDATE statement [UPDATE `image` SET `FILE_UPLOAD_ID`=:p1, `UPDATED_AT`=:p2 WHERE image.ID=:p3] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`DATABASENAME`.`image`, CONSTRAINT `image_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`file_upload_id`) REFERENCES `file_upload` (`id`))]

I found that that error is caused because $upload->save() invokes BaseFileUpload->doSave(), which, among other things, re-triggers $image->save():

```
if ($this->collImages !== null) {
  foreach ($this->collImages as $referrerFK) {
    if (!$referrerFK->isDeleted()) {
      $affectedRows += $referrerFK->save($con);
    }
  }
}
```

... which means that FileUpload mirrors reverse references to it from other objects even though it itself is only ever *referenced*, not *referencing* anything else.

When I override Image->save() to first clear all mirrored references on linked FileUpload and and then call parent::save(), problem goes away:

```
public function save( PropelPDO $con = null )
{
  $upload = $this->getFileUpload();
  if ( null !== $upload && $upload->isModified() ) {
    $upload->clearAllReferences();
    $upload->save( $con );
    $this->setFileUpload( $upload );
  }
  return parent::save( $con );
}
```

This approach works but feels hacky. It could also only be used here because I'm easily able to restore external references once the $upload object is saved - in other cases it might not be as simple.

Is there any clean way to prevent re-triggering saving of $image->save() from $upload->save() - without interfering with Propel's default behaviour too much? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call save on the parent object (FileUpload) and Propel saves the child objects after you add them to the parent and call save on the parent.

```
<?php
$upload = new FileUpload();
$image = new Image();
$image2 = new Image();

// set required fields on $upload, $image, and $image2
// ....

$upload->addImage($image);
$upload->addImage($image2);
$upload->save(); // save upload and new images

?>
```